# finding different documents in same collection in mogodb-nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

below are the details :
**dispatch Collection**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580"),
        "dispatched" : false,
        "dispatchableItems" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a95110"),
                        "itemCategory" : "Accessories",
                        "itemName" : "key chain",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "AKCME1",
                        "itemCount" : 20,
                        "fixeditemCount" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a95111"),
                        "itemCategory" : "Handbags",
                        "itemName" : "kalinz purple long chain handbag",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "HKHE1",
                        "itemCount" : 5,
                        "fixeditemCount" : 1
                }
        ],
        "weekday" : "FR",
        "toBeDispatchedBy" : ObjectId("5e2696c683201450a8ddb1dc"),
        "toBeDispatchedTo" : ObjectId("5e2696f883201450a8ddb1df"),
        "toBeDispatchedOn" : ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z")
```

and there are multiple documents , one the document is

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89087"),
        "dispatched" : true,
        "dispatchableItems" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a00997"),
                        "itemCategory" : "Accessories",
                        "itemName" : "key chain",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "AKCME1",
                        "itemCount" : 30,
                        "giftCount" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be2cc13b7149d0a95678"),
                        "itemCategory" : "Handbags",
                        "itemName" : "kalinz purple long chain handbag",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "HKHE1",
                        "itemCount" : 10,
                        "giftCount" : 1
                }
        ],
        "weekday" : "FR",
        "toBeDispatchedBy" : ObjectId("5e2696c683201450a8ddb1dc"),
        "toBeDispatchedTo" : ObjectId("5e2696f883201450a8ddb1df"),
        "toBeDispatchedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")
```

**1: i need to show the documents for ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z") & ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")(i.e D-7 last week data ) 
2: i will get this from req.body {"toBeDispatchedBy","toBeDispatchedto"}** 
this is what i have tried

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'toBeDispatchedBy': ObjectId("5e2696c683201450a8ddb1dc"),
            "toBeDispatchedto": ObjectId("5e2696f883201450a8ddb1df"),
           '$or': [
                {
                    'toBeDispatchedOn': ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z")
                }, {
                    'toBeDispatchedOn': ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")
                }]}}])
```

but i am getting documents only for ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z") 
moreover this is the kind of reponse i actually need:

```
"dispatchDetails": [
                   {   "toBeDispatchedOn": ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z")
                        "itemCategory" : "Accessories",
                        "itemName" : "key chain",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "AKCME1",
                        "itemCount" : 30,
                        "giftCount" : 2,
                       "lastWeekData":[{"toBeDispatchedOn": ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")
                                        "itemCount" : 30,
                                        "giftCount" : 2}]
                },
                {
                        "itemCategory" : "Handbags",
                        "itemName" : "kalinz purple long chain handbag",
                        "city" : "mumbai",
                        "itemCode" : "HKHE1",
                        "itemCount" : 10,
                        "giftCount" : 1,
                        "lastWeekData":[{"toBeDispatchedOn": ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")
                                        "itemCount" : 30,
                                        "giftCount" : 2}]
                }
        ]
```

there are lots of documents in this collection i need to show the documents for the currentDay(toBeDispatchedOn) and D-7(toBeDispatchedOn-7) day on the basis of "toBeDispatchedBy","toBeDispatchedto" which i will get from req.body, i need to implement this query in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're using `mongoose`, you could do something like this:

```
const { toBeDispatchedBy, toBeDispatchedTo } = req.body;
const result = await Order.find({
  toBeDispatchedBy,
  toBeDispatchedTo,
  toBeDispatchedOn: {
    $in: [new Date("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z"), new Date("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")]
  }
});
```

You don't need to use aggregate for the simple finding operation.

Comment: will it give me the kind of response i am expecting ,if you can help me out in generating that kind of response i have posted a sample of the response in my question –, moreover the query is fetching documents of only ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z") date in mongoshell but empty array in nodejs @technophyle